# Returning custom columns when using search API sourceid

Tags: search, search-results, search-scope, rest

I am attempting to search a specific custom content type using SharePoint Online's REST Search API.  Here is the URL Request.

```
_api/search/query?sourceid='d0aa2c2e%2D7709%2D46f1%2D835a%2D244f483e4b0e'
```

The problem is that the content type has custom fields which I need returned.  The dataset returned does not show those custom fields.  I want to know if there is a way I can craft the URL to be sure to include my custom fields.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `selectproperties` as paul suggested

After adding it your query should look like below

```
_api/search/query?sourceid='d0aa2c2e%2D7709%2D46f1%2D835a%2D244f483e4b0e'&selectproperties='columnName1,columnName2'
```

Comment: Actually, it's `&selectproperties='columnName,columnName2'` AFAIK.

Comment: oops!

corrected the answer now, thanks for prompting

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'selectproperties' query string parameter